# Firefox changes select radio box with every refresh!

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm trying to add a select box dynamically to a page with two radio boxes, but the firefox behaviour is strange. Although the first radio button explicitly defined as checked, but selected changes when the page is refreshed (with F5).

The complete html is (view it [here](http://www.webdevout.net/test?01S&raw)):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="txt0"></div>
        <input value="10" type="radio" name="a" checked="checked">
        <input value="11" type="radio" name="a">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById('txt0').innerHTML = '<select name="sa"></select>';    
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Opera behaves normal (tested)

Comment: It is apparently doing this in FF 4, but not on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/c3Lrr/

Comment: jsFiddle has lots of script and displays the content dynamically. I had a complex problem with /my own web server/, but this is the simplified version.

Comment: I would totally submit it as a bug to FF team. The behaviour seems to have absolutely no logic behind it.

Comment: Well, it's also doing it when I copy it to my desktop and run it from there. The point where it seems to go wrong is when innerHTML gets set.

Comment: FF tries to remember the selected element but there are more elements when you leave to reload than when you come back (immediately). When you "leave" the page you've selected element 2 (the first radio), when you reload it selects element 2 (the second radio). When you "leave" again you've selected element 3 which doesn't exist on the reload. If it's any help, pressing shift-reload makes the behaviour consistent as this stops FF trying to remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some kind of cache problem. Did some testing:

- Refresh using CTRL-F5 (bypassing the cache settings) *worked*.
- Changing the name of the other radio-input *worked*.
- Supplying both inputs with an id didn't work.
- Placing #txt0 *after* the inputs *worked*.
- Adding the select-tag using appendChild didn't work
- Placing the radio-inputs in a
  separate div didn't work
- Using `checked` or `checked=true` didn't work
- Adding an option to the selectbox didn't work
- Placing a div between #txt0 and the first radio input didn't work
- Create Select tag after a timeout didn't work
- adding meta tags to prevent caching didn't work
- adding `document.forms[0].a[0].checked = 'checked'` `worked` (doh!)

Anyway, it is a [recognised Firefox problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=394782), so the only thing you can do is use one of the workarounds you find above and wait until ff solves it.